# readline and readlines methods missing from python 3.2?

Tags: python, readline, readlines

Did they remove [file.readline()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.readline) and [file.readlines()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.readlines) from python 3.2? If yes what did they replace it with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While there is no `file` type any more in Python 3.x, the various types in the `io` module that replace the old `file` type [still support `f.readline()` and `f.readlines()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readline).  You actually don't need those methods, though, since they can be substituted by `next(f)` and `list(f)`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) (well, tutorial) for Python 3.2.
`readline` and `readlines` are still a part of Python.

Answer (score 1):

No they did not.

```
f = open("file", "r")
f.readlines()
```

is working for me, Python 3.2.

EDIT: it produces an io object (not file).

Answer (score 0):

I had problems, too. However, when I included an

```
import readline
```

at the top of my script, everything worked fine. It appears that it has to be imported explicitly now.